# ngrx - select multiple items from store for multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

My problem is simple. I have 2 observables:

```
assetNodes$: Observable<Asset[]>;
isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;
```

I am selecting Observables for these 2 using the following code:

```
this.assetNodes$ = this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) => state.dashboard.assetTree));
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) =>
    {
      console.log(state)
      state.dashboard.assetTreeLoading
    }));
```

The variable `assetNodes$` works fine, but the second Observable `this.isLoading$` is never called (and hence no console.log). I believe this is due to the fact you can only select from the store once? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you subscribe to it?

Comment: @martin not explicitly no, I use it in my html, e.g. `[nbSpinner]="isLoading$ | async"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select more than once from the store.
I think it's because you aren't returning something in the second selector:

```
this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) =>
    {
      console.log(state);
      return state.dashboard.assetTreeLoading;
    }));
```